# Add a single or multiple API endpoints when accepting POST request?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, api-design

I have planned to build a multiple service endpoints such as these in order to update multiple entity items.

```
/api/order(orderInfo) [httppost]
/api/orderChangeCurrency(orderCurrency) [httppost]
/api/orderChangeClientName(orderClientName) [httppost]

public class orderInfo()
{
public int orderID {get;set;}
public int orderType {get;set;}
}

public class orderCurrency()
{
public int orderID {get;set;}
public int currencyID {get;set;}
}

public class orderClientName()
{
public int orderID {get;set;}
public string firstName{get;set;}
public stringlastName{get;set;}
}
```

But it crossed my mind to have a single endpoint instead that would do all of it

```
/api/order(orderExtendedInfo) [httppost]

public class orderExtendedInfo()
{
public int orderID {get;set;}
public orderInfo? OrderInfo{get;set;}
public orderCurrency? OrderCurrency{get;set;}
public orderClientName? OrderClientName{get;set;}
}
```

In this case I would have a business logic that would update entities based on the information provided (null values or not).

Is there a recommended practice or a rule for API endpoints in this specific case?

Comment: What way of "recommended" are you looking for? Be more specific

Comment: I am just looking for an API design practice for this particular case.

Comment: I think you are okay in your approach. The only thing is that if you follow REST, your approach is kind of wrong. Rest focus on resources so, you should not handle multiple resources in on method. But, this is just "purist" REST guidelines and I don't see it applying much in my very day work.

Comment: @jpgrassi when you say ok in approach, are you referring to single or multiple endpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's quite a broad question and might be more suitable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com but I'll drop some considerations anyway.

First of all, your API design should be geared towards the users of your API. If your API will be a public facing API you might consider [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). It's is a widely used (and debated) architectural style and lots of programmers are used to this style. A very useful list of recommendations on designing a RESTful API can be [found here](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Second, you should consider the consumability of your API. To take your design as an example: would it be logical for a consumer to update the entities one by one or would it be more logical to update one or more or even all entities at once?

Third, you'll have to take database transactions into account. When all entities should be updated in one atomic operation then you cannot provide three endpoints.

Personally, I'm quite fond of REST so I'll happily provide an example for your use case.

**Example**

First let me introduce a new entity:

```
public class OrderLine 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

Endpoints

```
POST /api/orders                  # creates a new order 
GET  /api/orders                  # gets all orders
GET  /api/orders/1                # gets order 1
POST /api/orders/1/orderlines     # creates a new order line for order 1.
GET  /api/orders/1/orderlines/1   # gets order line 1 of order 1
GET  /api/orderlines/{id}         # gets order line 1
```

If you need to update multiple entities in a single operation you could do it like this:

Create a model for the update:

```
public class EditOrder
{
    public int orderID {get;set;}
    public int orderType {get;set;}
    public int currencyID {get;set;}
    public string firstName{get;set;}
    public string lastName{get;set;}
}
```

And then use this endpoint

```
PUT  /api/orders/1
```

And this method

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, EditOrder editOrder)
{
    // retrieve current Order, OrderCurrency and OrderClient
    // update the entities 
    // save entities
}
```

Comment: You are right about all the facts. It should be PUT and not POST when updating when updating an order. You are right regarding structure of endpoint, especially when placing orderlies in a format such as /api/orders/{id}/orderlines (it seems there is a duplicate/or similar endpoint /api/orders/1/orderlines/1 and /api/orderlines/{id} ). I am just not sure if there is no need to do an atomic update would it be wiser to update multiple entities in a single operation or divide it to multiple endpoints (from end user perspective). From BL perspective it would be completely different issue.

Comment: For example https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#update-ticket is basically updating entire ticket within a single endpoint (except audits, comments etc) which are similar to orderline from your example.

Comment: I added the duplicate endpoint to indicate that a resource can be accessed through multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement one Controller action method and three method in Business Layer like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/order")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SubmitOrder(OrderExtendedInfo info)
{
    var bl = new BusinessLayer();
    if(info.orderInfo.HasValue)
    {
        bl.UpdateOrderInfo(orderInfo);
    }
    if(info.orderCurrency.HasValue)
    {
        bl.UpdateOrderCurrency(orderCurrency);
    }
    if(info.orderClientName.HasValue)
    {
        bl.UpdateOrderClientName(orderClientName);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution it would take three round trips to DB to make all the updates. But lets say that is not a problem, the main concern it should I have single or multiple API endpoints.